# Proof of sum equals to $0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Proof that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^kk^m{n \choose k} = 0$$
for every $n>m$ and $m>1$.

I tried to use properties of ${n \choose k}.\;$
I tried to use $${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k} + {n-1 \choose k-1}$$
and using induction got stuck here
$$\sum_{k=1}^t (-1)^kk^m{t-1 \choose k-1} = 0$$, where $t = n - 1$.

Comment: Please show the work resulting from your try, and include it in your post.  Show us the properties you used, how far you got in your try, and what specifically leaves you stuck after your claimed "try".

Comment: You should probably also specify the values of $m$ that you're considering. I'm guessing that you mean for nonnegative or positive integers $m$.

Comment: Thanks, jack jones, for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show the identity with the help of generating functions. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
  [z^m]e^{kz}=[z^m]\left(1+kz+\frac{(kz)^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)=\frac{k^m}{m!}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain for integers $1\leq m< n$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^kk^m}&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}m![z^m]e^{kz}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^nm![z^m]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(e^z\right)^k(-1)^{n-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^nm![z^m]\left(e^z-1\right)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^nm![z^m]\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)^n\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=0
> }\end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator as shown in (1).
- In (3) we do a small rearrangement.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we see the smallest power of $z$ is $n$.

Comment: Of course, given $n>m>1,$ we arrive at the answer 0.  Thanks! +1

Comment: It looks like there is a factor of $(-1)^n$ missing somewhere around $(2)$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn: Typo  corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks false. If $0=m<n=1$ we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kk^m\binom{n}{k} = -1^0\binom{1}{1}=-1\neq0\ .$$

Comment: check edited version

Comment: And it might help to show what happens when $1\lt m\lt n$.

Comment: Daniel  The fact that you jumped into answer prior to knowing how m relates to n, (and not taking the time to even ask, (e.g., see the inequality above), lead you to posting a trivial and non-applicable argument.

Comment: And why would you have even guessed that m could be $0$?

Comment: @amWhy This is not my fault, but rather the OP's, since he didn't put all of the conditions in the question.

Comment: Daniel It is partly your fault for assuming things that were not stated in the question.  You came up with a trivial counterexample, exploiting what wasn't said, and avoiding addressing the reasonable problem, and not having waited for further clarification.  In any case, you jumped the gun, made assumptions that $m$ could be zero, to come up with what turns out to be an invalid claim that the statement is false, therefore.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two hints that lead in different directions. First, consider the number of surjective functions from an $m$-element set to an $n$-element set. Second consider the coefficient of $x^my^n$ in the generating function $\exp(y(e^x - 1))$.